# Sort piped to uniq unexpected output

Tags: sorting, awk, cat, uniq

I have a file that looks like this:

```
"string",192.168.1.0,,TX,192.168.1.2,,,100,0,0,10,10,10,,
"string",192.168.1.0,,TX,192.168.1.1,,,100,0,0,10,10,10,,
"string",192.168.1.0,,TX,192.168.1.4,,,100,0,0,10,10,10,,
"string",192.168.1.0,,TX,192.168.1.2,,,100,0,0,10,10,10,,
```

With this command I expect it to pull the second ip address, and basically list how many times that IP is listed in this file.

```
cat originalFile.txt | awk -F "," '{print $5}' | sort | uniq -c > outputFile.txt
```

This sorts incorrectly.  I want the output file to look like below (organized by the first column)

```
1 192.168.1.1
1 192.168.1.4
2 192.168.1.2
```

I've tried changing the sort section to

```
sort -n -k1
```

I think the problem is that i'm sorting before it's performing uniq, but any other order seems to break the process.  Right now my fix is to just run two commands like this.

```
    cat originalFile.txt | awk -F "," '{print $5}' | sort | uniq -c > outputFile1.txt
    sort -n -k1 outputFile1.txt > outputFile2.txt
```

Obviously using a temporary file for this isn't ideal, and I'm sure I just need to slightly modify this and put it in a different order.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `uniq -c` will sort by the items themselves, not the count.  If you want to sort by the count, you'll need to pipe the output to sort one more time.

Answer (score 1):

Sort for the uniq, then later sort for the final order:

```
cat originalFile.txt | awk -F "," '{print $5}' | sort | uniq -c | sort -n
```